# Knex/Bookshelf: How to Use Postgres Schema in All Queries/Commands

Tags: node.js, postgresql, bookshelf.js, knex.js

I am writing an application with Knex, Bookshelf, and Postgres. I would like all Postgres commands issued from my application to be on tables in one schema. **Is there a way I can accomplish this without specifying `.withSchema('my_schema_name')` for each individual query/command?**

Ideally, I could specify the schema in the knexfile.js, but I don't see a way to do this.

I have already tried:

- prepending the table name with 'my_schema_name.'
- issuing a USE SCHEMA command at the launch of my application

Both of these resulted in various errors.

Comment: A related Bookshelf issue: https://github.com/tgriesser/bookshelf/issues/458

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was actually to pretend the tableName with 'my_schema.'. (Notice the dot)

The error I had seen when I tried this initially was due to something else.

Answer (score 1):

Your connection should call `SET search_path TO my_schema, public;` after being initialized. This is a connection (session) property and it should do what you are asking for.